# Passing value from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inline-editing

OK, i asked a very similar question recently and I got good answers back. However, I probably did not express my problem accurately so I will give it another go here:

This is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<h3  class="editable">@Model.Title</h3>

<input type="submit" value="submit">   

}
```

The `<h3>` has the class `"editable"` which in this case means it can be edited by an inline-editor.

```
@Model.Title
```

Is a properties from my database that I would like to be able to change with the *inline-editor*.

This code would generate the same result:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h3  class="editable">@Model.Title</h3>

    <input type="text" id="testinput" name="testinput" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
   } 
Controller:


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FAQ(string testInput)
        {


            page.Title = testInput;

            return View();
        }
```

Allthough, this does not use the inline-editor which I would like.

**Is there maybe a way to treat the `<h3>` as if it was a `textbox` allowing me to send whatever is in there to the controller?**

I want to make clear that I do NOT want to send `@model.title` to the controller directly.
I want to send the value created by clicking on the `<h3>` and using the inline-editor to change it.

Thank you!

Comment: You may need to have your own framework or use an existing one to do this named x-editable.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form in this fashion the controller will try and match it to the correct object type. If you want to just pass back 1 or 2 objects try using the action links. These should allow you to pass in the values with names to match your control methods.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
Im pretty new to mvc, would you mind posting a code example if you got the time?
And also, when you say that the controller will try to match with name..This would mean that if I could give the h3 a name, it would match? But can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.ShopItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shop";
}

<h2>ShopView</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h3 class="editable">@Model.Name</h3>
    @Html.TextBox("Cost",0.00D,null)
    <input type="submit" title="Submit" />
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class ShopItem
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal? Cost { get; set; }

        public ShopItem()
        {
            Id = null;
            Name = "";
            Cost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Shop()
    {
        ShopItem item = new ShopItem();
        return View(item);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Shop(decimal Cost)
    {
        ShopItem item = new ShopItem();
        item.Cost = Cost;

        return View(item);
    }
```

If you put this in the HomeController, to test it. You will see my input has a strong type, and matches my action inputs

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, i tried to paste your code into another project to see if could lear something from it...Got an error on the @html.textbox

 CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object, string)' and 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBox(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, object, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object>)'